# liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: ChangeLogFile does not exists

Tags: java, liquibase

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //execute("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/JAVA_Test", "Admin", "123456", "org.postgresql.Driver");
    execute("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:5432/Liquibase_JAVA", "sa", "123456!", "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
}

public static void execute(String url, String userName, String password, String driver) throws Exception  {
    DatabaseConnection dbConnection = new DatabaseConnection(url, driver, userName, password);
    Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
    Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(conn));
    String changeLog = "/job_executor/liquibasechangelog/databaseChangeLog.xml";
    Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase(changeLog, new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), database);
    liquibase.update(null);
    conn.close();
}
```

I have my changeLogFile inside my project. It's kind of weird that i'm getting an error changeLogFile.xml does not exists.

Can anyone help me with this, THanks

Comment: You reference `changeLogFile.xml` but in your description, but in your code you're using `databaseChangeLog.xml`. Are you sure the file with the name in the code exists?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely your change log file is not there:

```
/job_executor/liquibasechangelog/databaseChangeLog.xml
```

but there:

```
job_executor/liquibasechangelog/databaseChangeLog.xml
```

Please notice the / missing in the second path so it will be relative, not absolute.

Comment: Did you try to execute

     `cat job_executor/liquibasechangelog/databaseChangeLog.xml`

from the place where you are executing your java?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it, by adding the liquibasechangelog folder (where my xml files resides) to the build path and then by referring it just by the file name instead of path to the file name

just like this

> String changeLog = "databaseChangeLog.xml";

THanks @DavidX @MichalRorat